# Android app crash on 3G slow connection but works fine over wifi

Tags: android

I have a small android app that basically perform a http call to retrieve some web page info and parse it locally for display purpose.

It works fine on wifi. However, the app crashes randomly when on 3G (not all the time, but frequently enough) after submitting the http query. Often I was able to just restart the app, try to perform the same task and it will work as it's intended to. I am kinda stuck trying to debug this problem. Is it caused by slow internet connection? packet drop? What kind of checking code I can put in there to prevent this from happening?

Some example code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HashMap<String, String[]> hmSearchResults = null;       
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        String resultPage = client.execute(getMethod, responseHandler);

        // I am think the error is here if resultPage == null due to 
        // whatever reason, is there any check I can put around 
        // client.execute?
        hmSearchResults = ParseHtml.getSearchResultText(resultPage, numRequestResults);

    } catch (Throwable t) {     
        Utility.showToast(this,"Request failed: " + t.toString());
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message in logcat?

Comment: Yeah, what is the error and what thread are you running this in?

Comment: The tasks are performed in the doInBackground() of AsyncTask. On the phone itself it just creates app force closed error. I'll try recreate the error on debugging mode and post the logcat error here.

Comment: Are you getting an application not responding type of force close?  Perhaps something in the foreground is improperly waiting on the background server access; that it works on the second try suggests its time related since things like host name resolution and routing can take advantage of caching from the first attempt.

Comment: Check if resultPage is null and if so, don't try to process it.  Try to get it again, or tell the user it's not working, or something.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has been able to answer this. I'm having the same problem. There are no errors or warnings in the logcat. Just random crashes. Target is Android 2.1. I really hope someone posts a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from an activity or from a service? In my own apps I only have this problem if I run the code from a service; it works perfectly on wifi, but crashes on 3G, and never crashes in an activity.

The only fix for this I could find for fixing the service crash is as follows:

- if on wifi, and using a service, use AsyncTask
- if on 3G, and using a service, run on main thread
- else use AsyncTask

Hope this helps.